# Choosing axis in plotyy

Tags: matlab, plot, axes

This should be quite simple, although I was not able to find a solution in the Matlab docs.

I have to plot two or more sets of data, that can be fit in two different ranges. So I can use plotyy to manage this.

What I want to do, is being able, once created a plot, to overwrite or simple add traces to one of the two axes, selectively. I tried to catch the parameters returned by plotyy, but I wasn't able to decypher them.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MATLAB documentation on [`plotyy`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/plotyy.html) states that

```
[ha, h1, h2] = plotyy(...)
```

returns the handles of the two axes created in `ha` and the handles of the graphics objects from each plot in `h1` and `h2`. `ha(1)` is the left axes and `ha(2)` is the right axes.

So the first argument returned by `plotyy` is a handle to each of the axes created. To plot on the left axis use `plot(ha(1), x, y)` and to plot on the right axis use `plot(ha(2), x, y)`.

If you don't need the handles to the graphics objects plotted, you can just use `ha = plotyy(...)`. Otherwise, `h1` and `h2` returns the handles to the lines (or other graphics object) plotted in the call to `plotyy`. So, following the example in the documentation, setting the line styles of the two lines can be done like so:

```
set(h1, 'LineStyle', '--')
set(h2, 'LineStyle', ':')
```

Answer (score 2):

The first output of PLOTYY is a vector of axis handles.

```
AX = PLOTYY(..)
```

`AX(1)` will be the handle to the first axis.
`AX(2)` will be the handle to the second axis.

To add a plot to one of the axis, simply use PLOT or LINE.

```
plot(AX(1), ...)

line('parent',AX(1),'xdata',...)
```

Comment: thank you! but in this way how can I pass both the axes values to the **line** function?

Comment: You can plot on each axes independently with two calls to PLOT or LINE:
plot(AX(1), ...)
plot(AX(2), ...)

Comment: no sorry I was referring to the fact that if i try to pass **line** as you wrote, with the variable containing the x-axis and y-axis values, it returns an error; what variable type should be passed with 'xdata'?

Comment: You will probably want to use a double.
E.g.,
line('parent',AX(1),'xdata',xvals,'ydata',yvals);
where xvals and yvals are doubles.